# How to add an x-auth-token in a POST/GET request header in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a /register path which returns user a token (generated by auth middleware). This authenticated user will be able to view and post. However, I don't know how to store this token in a broswer (or database) and how to include it in the header via x-auth-token. In postman, I could just add it in a header, but I don't know how to do it in an HTML form.

auth.js (Authentication middleware)

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('config');

// middleware function, next so it moves on to the next middlware
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  //get the token from header
  const token = req.header('x-auth-token');

  //Check if not token
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'No token, authorization denied' });
  }

  //Verify token if exist
  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get('jwtSecret'));
    req.user = decoded.user;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(401).json({ msg: 'Token is not valid' });
  }
};
```

posts.js

```
// @ route    POST api/posts
// @desc      Create a post
// @access    Private
router.post(
  '/',
  [
    auth,
    [
      check('title', 'Title is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty()
    ]
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
    try {
      const user = await User.findById(req.user.id).select('-password');

      //user information (name and avatar) comes from the databse, not the request
      const newPost = new Post({
        title: req.body.title,
        body: req.body.body,
        name: user.name,
        avatar: user.id,
        user: req.user.id
      });
      const post = await newPost.save();
      res.json(post);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
  }
);
```

post.handlebars (Post form)

```
 <form class="form" action="/api/posts" method="post" >
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="What is your idea?" name="title" requried>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Let us know more detail. What is the story. How did you come up with it? 
Why do you think people would need it etc" name="body">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Post" class="button green-button" />

            </form>
```

users.js (registration)

```
.
.
.

      jwt.sign(
        payload,
        config.get('jwtSecret'),
        { expiresIn: 60 * 60 * 100 },
        (err, token) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.json({ token });
          // req.flash('You seccessfully registered your account');
          // res.redirect('/user/login');
        }
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server error');
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, you'd want to store the token as a cookie in the browser.  Cookies are always sent with requests to the backend, so you don't need to have special logic to include the header.